# Interfacing DS1302 - is the schematic I found correct?

Tags: microcontroller, gpio, rtc

On the following [website](http://www.danduino.dk/shop/upgrade-diy-ec1515b-ds1302-light-control-rotation-led-electronic-clock-kit-51-scm-learning-board/) there is a project of a 7-segment clock, which uses [DS1302](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1302.pdf) as RTC. The DS1302 is connected to the microcontroller in the way that I don't really understand. Can someone please answer a few questions?

- Why has the author of the schematic added capacitors C5 and C4? AFAIK there is no need for additional capacitors, if crystal has specified load capacitance of 6pF. Is it because they've used a crystal with different load capacitance?
- Why has the author of the schematic added pull-up resistors R13, R14, R15? AFAIK, they're also not needed. Are they driving those lines in open drain manner? If yes, why?

Please find the interfacing schematic:

[image: partial schematic showing DS1302]

[image: partial schematic showing microcontroller pins connected to DS1302]

Comment: I would just connect RST directly to the IO of microcontroller, the IO would be then configured as push-pull output. I don't need then this pull up resistor. This is also a recommended way of connection in datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Hobbyists don't always get the details correct, if it works they are happy. Follow the vendor recommendations.

The pull-ups are not only not needed, they can potentially cause harm since the DS1302 has internal *pull-downs*. I would guess that the author was accustomed to seeing pull-ups for I2C interfaces and thought that this was similar. The DS1302 doesn't use I2C or SPI, it is a custom interface.